# Re-tagging when editing question!

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing, questions

This is just a small request to all who do the great job of editing posts (especially questions) and improving the quality of the site this way:

*Please, always check whether the question is properly tagged!* Tagging is very important for ease of searching on the site, and for the "Related" panel on the right.

It has happened to me plenty of times that a post was edited by an experienced user, but not re-tagged. Several times I was just doing an edit myself, got the message "this post has been already edited by someone else", only to find that the other edit did not retag and it has to be done.

Thanks for doing the job!

Comment: Probably lockstep and doncherry and a few others made us a little too lazy :)

Comment: It would be great to have an answer to this 'question' that gives guidelines/education on tagging :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that proper tags are very important, but I guess some people who are great at editing posts are less certain about proper tags. To those I'd say: Do the editing and leave the tags untouched if you're uncertain. Then still other people can come and retag, why not? Let me point out that retagging [doesn't push posts into becoming community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62673).

Comment: Even if it is hard to find the right tags it seems far easier to spot incorrect tags. So many people who edit but do not retag should often at least be competent enough to remove incorrect tags.